# Ruby Net::HTTP::Options does not allow response body

Tags: ruby, json, web-services, rest, net-http

I am writing a script to test various web-services in ruby. To make http requests thus far I have been using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) but today I realized I needed to make an OPTIONS request and retrieve some JSON from the response.

Unfortunately ruby does not currently support this: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8429

Does anyone know of gem that supports this or some other way to get this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative which supports lot of options

https://rubygems.org/gems/curb

Comment: Curb looks like it would work and I might have to take that route but as this script will be passed around to many different developers I would prefer to use self-contained gems. On my machine (Windows 7) it looks like I have to download libcurl and add it to my env variables. Would be nice to just bundle install then run the script.

Answer (score -1):

[Mechanize Gem](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)

Try this gem it's very usefull and simple in use. I use it for parsing and another different tasks.

Comment: I can't seem to find any of the documentation supporting OPTIONS, thanks for the advice though.